# What HTTP Protocol can I use if I need to GET something from the server but I also need to send a requestbody?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am using SpringBoot...
I can not use GET protocol and include a body, but I am not going to create or update anything on the server so I do not want to use POST or PUT, any other protocol that acts like a GET with body?

if you wonder what I need to send in that body it is an url parameter, like for example http://somewebsite.com/stuff/etc and I feel that putting this inside a request body is better than putting it as a requestparam

Comment: GET requests typically use  urlparams to send data to the server  `https://example.com/path/to/resource?param=value&otherparam=othervalue` Furthermore, while used only very seldom, it's not per se forbidden to send a request body with a GET reqeust

Comment: @derpirscher I just tried to send a url param and it worked, but since it is an url that also contains requestparams and stuff I am afraid that it might not work in some case? this is the request i send in postman, and inside my server I ping the application that comes in the urlToPing param localhost:8080/proxy-ping?urlToPing=myapp.toping.apps.io/ping

Comment: HTTP doesn't prohibit GET payloads, however, it explicitly states that such a payload doesn't have a defined meaning and that multi-purpose clients/caches may reject it. If you only use such requests in internal applications, go for it. However, POST should be used if the semantics of other operations doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Then you have to properly urlencode your parameter values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can not use GET protocol and include a body, but I am not going to create or update anything on the server so I do not want to use POST or PUT, any other protocol that acts like a GET with body?

Your best bet, where suitable, would be to mimic how HTML forms work; which is to say having a family of resources with identifiers that are filled in by the client (in general, via URI templates -- often via query parameters as would happen with an HTML form).

When that's not appropriate: as of 2022-11, your best bet is POST.  It's not a great answer (in particular, general purpose HTTP components won't know that the semantics of the request are safe), but it is the best option available of the [registered methods](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml#methods).

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of "
> "this action isn’t worth standardizing." -- [Roy Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

Eventually, the [HTTPbis-wg](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/about/) will finalize the [safe-method-with-a-body](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/) proposal, and at that point that will become a much better option than POST (for the cases that match the new semantics).